# Collada file mirrored when created with qgis2threejs in QGIS 2.18

Tags: qgis, qgis2threejs, collada

When I export a Collada file from QGIS 2.18.23 using the amazing QGIS2threejs plugin version 1.4.2, my Collada file comes into Blender and Sketchup with the East West mirrored. This is not the case in the browser or when I export an `.obj`.

I don't know of a way to fix it in Sketchup or Blender because it would require being both flipped and turned insideout. I know I could use Blender to convert the `.obj` to a `.dae` but I need my students who will have QGIS and Sketchup installed but not Blender to be able to export and use a Collada file.

The .dae is a of a lidar derived DEM in MA State Plane Feet.

In QGIS 3 the plugin has been updated and .gltf is the only export option.

An alternative conversion process that results in a .dae would be acceptable.

Comment: i think it might be the [right hand rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-hand_rule) here?

Comment: or possibly a rotation of the order of the axes : xyz / yzx / zxy

Comment: I tried a different CRS in case it was a issue there. No luck. If it helps all of the exports, .dae and .obj come into blender with North down but only the .dae are mirrored. If it is a right hand or coordinate order mix up any thing I can easiliy do on my side?

Comment: I don't see an option to export to collada from Qgis2ThreeJS ([the docs](https://qgis2threejs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ExportSettings.html) claim there's a webpage template that lets you do this, but I don't see the option in QGIS3/Mac). If you could edit your question to mention how you do this (and which version of QGIS) I'll see if I can reproduce this. Collada files supposedly have an orientation matrix in the .dae file so there should be some way to fix this. Alsowhat are you exporting, is it a DEM-derived mesh or models used for points? If it's a DEM it could be a negative y pixel value

Comment: Thanks Steven. The export option has been removed in the QGIS 3 version. In EPSG 3857 the X coordinate is negative which could result in what I am seeing.